# Laravel token mismatch when uploading a file that's too large

Tags: upload, laravel, token, mismatch

I'm using Laravel 4, and on an email form where I allow users to add attachments, I'm getting a token mismatch error when I try to submit a file that's beyond the post_max_size set in my php.ini. I put these lines in csrf filter to try to debug:

```
Log::debug(Session::token());
Log::debug(print_r($_POST, true));
Log::debug(Input::get('_token'));
Log::debug(Session::token() != Input::get('_token'));
```

Predictably, $_POST was empty, so the session token is always getting compared to null. But is there any way to gracefully let the user know the file is too large instead of throwing this error?

I'm using a javascript validator as well, but I don't want to rely solely on javascript to avoid this error getting thrown.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question, but I came across it and I couldn't really find anything explaining a solution to this problem. So, I figured I would post my solution.

I'm using Laravel 4.1, and in app/filters.php I changed Route::filter('csrf'. function() to this:

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
    {
        if (empty($_POST)) {
            $post_size = trim(ini_get('post_max_size'));
            $post_size = substr($post_size, 0, -1);
            $post_size = ($post_size * 1024) * 1024;

            if ($post_size < Request::header('Content-Length')) {
                $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), []);

                $messages = $validator->errors();
                $messages->add('file size', 'Files Cannot Exceed ' . ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));

                return Redirect::back()->withErrors($messages);
            }
        }

        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

Obviously other things besides just an overly large image could cause the Content-Length to overflow, but it is pretty unlikely so I figured it would be a reasonable risk.

Answer (score 2):

Check this link below, apparently the issue is caused by exceeding the maximum upload size..
[solved](http://laravel.io/forum/02-20-2014-l40-csrf-tokenmismatchexception-when-uploading-large-files)